# Accessing a file through Web service and Opening it using FileStream c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, filestream

I have a list of documents connected to a Contract Number, which are being displayed in the application by the help of a web service.

The documents shown have a href to open the file based on the type of document they are.(ex .txt||.xlsx||.pdf)

here's how i'm trying to do it. But its not working

```
 public FileStreamResult _EDMSDocument(long DocNbr)
    {
        eDOCSWS.edmsWSAppSoapClient service = new eDOCSWS.edmsWSAppSoapClient();
        eDOCSWS.edmsDocument doc = new eDOCSWS.edmsDocument();
        eDOCSWS.edmsFolder fldr = new eDOCSWS.edmsFolder();
        string strToken = "";
        string lib = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["edocsLibrary"];
        eDOCSWS.edmsResponse login = default(eDOCSWS.edmsResponse);
        login = service.loginAsUser(lib, 8, "xxxxx", "yyyyyy", "", "1.0.0", ref strToken);
        doc = service.getDocumentByIdentifier(strToken, lib, DocNbr,"");

        long vid;
        vid = doc.propVersions[doc.propIdxHighestVersion].propVersionID;
        long lngBlockCounter = 0;
        byte[] strbuffer;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        do
        {
            strbuffer = service.getFileBlock(strToken, lib, DocNbr, vid, 16384, lngBlockCounter);

            ms.Write(strbuffer, 0, strbuffer.Length);

        } while (strbuffer.Length == 0);

        return new FileStreamResult(ms, doc.propVersions[0].propMIMEType);

        //System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        //process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        //process.StartInfo.FileName = DefaultLogFilePath;
        //process.Start();
        //System.IO.File.Delete(DefaultLogFilePath);
        //return PartialView();
    }
```

A document number is displayed on the UI which has a href to call this function.
There weren't any errors thrown but neither are the files opened.

Thanks

Comment: You need to set Position = 0 on the memory stream before handing it to the file stream result.  Tada.

Comment: Does your code in some other area call the WriteFile method of the FileStreamResult object? You've constructed the object, but I don't see code in what's posted that actually performs the write to the stream.

Comment: Tried setting the position to 0, still doesn't work

Comment: David, no i am not calling a write file method.

Comment: Do i have to create a file write all the content to the file and then open with System.Diagnostic.Process.Start()?